# How does a BackupAgent work?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-backup-service

I'm looking at AndroidManifest files and I see entries for `android:backupAgent` and according to the Documentation `android:backupAgent` is

> The name of the class implementing BackupAgent to manage backup and restore of the application's settings to external storage.

But I can't find a `BackupAgent` interface or any other documentation.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BackupAgent's API is not solidified yet, so it's a hidden class.  [You can check it out on Android's git](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/android/app/BackupAgent.java;h=b207998409465dd5fdc87586a36575ef0ee71163;hb=HEAD), where there is this comment:

```
/**
 * This is the central interface between an application and Android's
 * settings backup mechanism.
 * 
 * @hide pending API solidification
 */
```

Comment: Looks like it's going to be handy!

Comment: Links seems to be broken now, can u please fix it...

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

All I can offer is the [source code for `android.app.BackupAgent`](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/android/app/BackupAgent.java;h=b207998409465dd5fdc87586a36575ef0ee71163;hb=HEAD) and the [source code for `android.backup.BackupManager`](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/android/backup/BackupManager.java;h=da1647a5abcb589d13468f8a50fdfd5cabe306f5;hb=HEAD).

`BackupAgent` is an abstract class and according to the javadoc in the source it "is the central interface between an application and Android's settings backup mechanism."  It has abstract `onBackup()` and `onRestore()` methods.

There is also `BackupManager`.  The javadoc says "`BackupManager` is the interface to the system's backup service.  Applications simply instantiate one, and then use that instance to communicate with the backup infrastructure."  It has a `dataChanged()` method to call to schedule a backup and a `beginRestoreSession()` method to start a restore.

Now, the interesting things in the code for `BackupManager` are:

```
*
* @hide pending API solidification
*/
```

and:

```
/** @hide TODO: REMOVE THIS */
public static final boolean EVEN_THINK_ABOUT_DOING_RESTORE = true;
```

So it seems that this is still a work in progress and the `EVEN_THINK_ABOUT_DOING_RESTORE` member variable is an easy way to disable backup functionality.  My guess is that it is disabled in production Android builds.